# Asp.net core на linux используя apache получаю Error 403

Tags: linux, apache, asp.net-core

Написал сайт на asp.net core (2.1) и пытаюсь развернуть его на linux (Centos 7) на Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS). Руководствуясь https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/linux-apache?view=aspnetcore-2.2#monitor-the-app произвёл следующие настройки: 
1) VirtualHost в apache (изменил порт, ServerName и ServerAlias. В остальном точно так же)
2) Установил и настроил Kestrel (полностью по примеру, изменил лишь дирректории)

Kestrel и apache запустились без проблем.
Проверяю как всё запустилось коммандой "curl -Is http://localhost:8080 | head -1" и получаю "HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden".
Через браузер получаю следущее сообщение:

---

Proxy Error

The proxy server received an invalid response from an upstream server.
The proxy server could not handle the request GET /... .

Reason: Error reading from remote server

---

Выдал файлу определения службы все права для всех. Размещён в той же директории как в иснтрукции: /etc/systemd/system/kestrel- ... .service

Внёс изменения в ConfigureServices (на сайте):

```
services.Configure<ForwardedHeadersOptions>(options =>
        {
          options.KnownProxies.Add(System.Net.IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"));
          options.ForwardedHeaders = ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedFor | ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedProto;
        });
```

Не помогло, всё так же 403 ошибка. На всякий случай укажу, на сайте реализована аутентификация. Сайт компилировал специально для linux и portable, разницы нет. Из студии запускается без проблем, разместил portable в IIS так же всё работает.

Собственно вопросы:
1) Как избавиться от этой 403 ошибки?
2) Возможно ли напрямую проверить как работает настроенный Kestrel, то-есть напрямую передавать html запросы, что бы убедиться в его корректной работе.

Comment: А если через Nginx или вообще напрямую через Kestrel?

Comment: через Nginx не пробовал, он пока даже не установлен. Что значит напрямую через Kestrel, то-есть предлагаете обратиться не по порту 8080, а по 5000?

Comment: Да, по умолчанию приложение слушает 5000 порт, попробуйте по нему зайти.

Comment: Попробовал коммандой  "curl -Is http://localhost:5000 | head -1", получаю "HTTP/1.1 503 Service Unavailable". Попробовал отключить Kestrel и запустить через dotnet и в дополнительном терминале, убедившись, что приложение запустилось, вновь той же командой получил ту же 503 ошибку.